# Are all subintervals of $[0,1]$ a sigma algebra?

Tags: measure-theory

I was reading the answer posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220248/understanding-borel-sets), and just can't understand one thing. Quote:

> the collection of all subintervals of $[0,1]$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra

however, earlier it has been stated that:

> the Borel sets of $[0,1]$ is a collection which is a $\sigma$-algebra

The first quote is false, because the complement of, say, $[0.5, 0.7]$ is not a subinterval of $[0,1]$, so the collection of all subintervals of $[0,1]$ is not a sigma algebra - correct? (*)

Is the second quoted statement true because we're not restricting ourselves to subintervals of $[0,1]$, but allow sets that are 'outside' $[0,1]$, so for instance the complement of $[0.5, 0.7]$ can be one of the Borel sets?

What it intuitively tells me is that Borel sets of $[0,1]$ contain a lot more than just subintervals of $[0,1]$.

Edit: I'm actually not sure how this

> Combine these two results and we have that the Borel sets of
>   $[0,1]$ is a collection which is a $\sigma$-algebra, and it contains all
>   the subintervals of $[0,1]$.

follows from the two points mentioned earlier the answer (1) sigma additivity of probability, 2) probability of choosing a point from interval is the length of that interval).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complement of an interval is an interval, or a union of two intervals.  It follows that the set of *finite unions* of intervals is closed under complementation (and, obviously, finite unions).

But it's not a $\sigma$-algebra, however, because it is not closed under countable unions.  So the first quote is *true*, and it's true even if we look at finite unions of intervals.

The collection of Borel sets is a $\sigma$-algebra basically by definition, since a Borel set is constructed from intervals using countable operations.  In fact, the collection of Borel sets is exactly the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the set of open intervals.

Comment: So the collection of Borel sets on [0,1] is made of all intervals from [0,1] plus non-intervals necessary to make it a sigma algebra?

Comment: @user5539357 You can think of it that way, though you might have trouble turning that into a rigorous definition.  I would either say that it is a) the $\sigma$-algebra consisting of countable unions of intervals, or b) the intersection of all $\sigma$-algebras containing the intervals.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited the question, as there's one more thing I'd like to clarify.

Comment: @user5539357 I don't know why you're asking such specific questions about an answer in another thread.  I think that Asaf's point is that the Borel sets are the smallest $\sigma$-algebra which allow for a notion of probability, but his point is informal and so nobody but him can really answer this question.

Comment: Last question - borel sigma algebra is the smallest sigma algebra containing all open sets (if it contains open sets, then it must also contain all their complements - all closed sets). But does it also mean it's the smallest sigma algebra containing all intervals? If it's true, I don't really see why.

Comment: @user5539357 Any open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable union of open intervals, so any $\sigma$-algebra containing open intervals must contain all opens.

Comment: Actually the set $\{[0,0.3] \cup [0.5,1]\}$ is not an interval, but a set. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics) Complement of an interval usually is not an interval.

Comment: @user5539357 You're quite right about that, this was an oversight.  What I've written should now be correct.